# Kafka: Get broker host from ZooKeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

For particular reasons I need to use both - `ConsumerGroup` (a.k.a. high-level consumer) and `SimpleConsumer` (a.k.a. low-level consumer) to read from Kafka. For `ConsumerGroup` I use ZooKeeper-based config and am completely satisfied with it, but `SimpleConsumer` requires seed brokers to be instantiated.

I don't want to keep list of both - ZooKeeper and broker hosts. Thus, I'm looking for a way to **automatically discover brokers** for a particular topic **from ZooKeeper**.

Because of some indirect information I *belief* that these data is stored in ZooKeeper under one of the following paths:

- `/brokers/topics/<topic>/partitions/<partition-id>/state`
- /brokers/ids/

However, when I try to read data from these nodes, I'm getting serialization error (I'm using `com.101tec.zkclient` for this):

> org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkMarshallingError: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B226A6D
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.serialize.SerializableSerializer.deserialize(SerializableSerializer.java:37)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.derializable(ZkClient.java:740)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:773)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:761)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:750)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:744)
>     ... 64 elided
>   Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B226A6D
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.serialize.TcclAwareObjectIputStream.(TcclAwareObjectIputStream.java:30)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.serialize.SerializableSerializer.deserialize(SerializableSerializer.java:31)
>     ... 69 more

I can write and read custom Java objects (e.g. Strings) without any problem, so I believe it's not a problem of a client, but rather tricky encoding. Thus, I want to know:

1. If this is the right way to go, **how to read these nodes properly**?
2. If the whole approach is wrong, **what is the right one**?

Comment: One tool that I found helpful to poke around in the Zookeeper data is this one: https://code.google.com/p/zooviewer/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is the way of what one of my colleagues did to get a list of Kafka brokers. I think it's a correct way when you want to get a broker list dynamically.

Here is an example code that shows how to get the list.

```java
public class KafkaBrokerInfoFetcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper("localhost:2181", 10000, null);
        List<String> ids = zk.getChildren("/brokers/ids", false);
        for (String id : ids) {
            String brokerInfo = new String(zk.getData("/brokers/ids/" + id, false, null));
            System.out.println(id + ": " + brokerInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the code onto the cluster consisting of three brokers results in

```
1: {"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1428512949385","host":"192.168.0.11","version":1,"port":9093}
2: {"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1428512955512","host":"192.168.0.11","version":1,"port":9094}
3: {"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1428512961043","host":"192.168.0.11","version":1,"port":9095}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply. Could you please also post reference to the ZooKeeper client library you are using in your code? On my side, I figured out how to fix an error I described and will post alternative solution using `com.101toc.ZkClient` which comes with Kafka libraries. Anyway, I accept your answer as totally valid.

Comment: It should be import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper;

Comment: +1  tooo simple and tooo efficient way to get the information about kafka (brokes, topics, partitions per topic ...etc) Thanx. It needs nothing but `import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper`

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that Kafka uses `ZKStringSerializer` to read and write data into znodes. So, to fix the error I only had to add it as a last parameter in `ZkClient` constructor:

```scala
val zkClient = new ZkClient(zkQuorum, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10000, ZKStringSerializer)
```

Using it, I wrote several useful functions for discovering broker ids, their addresses and other stuff:

```scala
import kafka.utils.Json
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient
import org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException


def listBrokers(): List[Int] = {
  zkClient.getChildren("/brokers/ids").toList.map(_.toInt)
}

def listTopics(): List[String] = {
  zkClient.getChildren("/brokers/topics").toList
}

def listPartitions(topic: String): List[Int] = {
  val path = "/brokers/topics/" + topic + "/partitions"
  if (zkClient.exists(path)) {
    zkClient.getChildren(path).toList.map(_.toInt)
  } else {
    throw new KafkaException(s"Topic ${topic} doesn't exist")
  }
}

def getBrokerAddress(brokerId: Int): (String, Int) = {
  val path = s"/brokers/ids/${brokerId}"
  if (zkClient.exists(path)) {
    val brokerInfo = readZkData(path)
    (brokerInfo.get("host").get.asInstanceOf[String], brokerInfo.get("port").get.asInstanceOf[Int])
  } else {
    throw new KafkaException("Broker with ID ${brokerId} doesn't exist")
  }
}

def getLeaderAddress(topic: String, partitionId: Int): (String, Int) = {
  val path = s"/brokers/topics/${topic}/partitions/${partitionId}/state"
  if (zkClient.exists(path)) {
    val leaderStr = zkClient.readData[String](path)
    val leaderId = Json.parseFull(leaderStr).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]].get("leader").get.asInstanceOf[Int]
    getBrokerAddress(leaderId)
  } else {
    throw new KafkaException(s"Topic (${topic}) or partition (${partitionId}) doesn't exist")
  }
}
```

Comment: what library is kafka.utils.ZkUtils?  'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.13'? That means we have to specify the version of kafka we are using?

Answer (score 9):

To do this using the shell:

```
zookeeper-shell myzookeeper.example.com:2181
ls /brokers/ids
  => [2, 1, 0]
get /brokers/ids/2
get /brokers/ids/1
get /brokers/ids/0
```

Answer (score 3):

actually, there is `ZkUtils` from within Kafka (at least for 0.8.x line), that you can use with one small caveat: you'll need to re-implement ZkStringSerializer that would convert strings as UTF-8 encoded byte arrays. If you'd like to use Java8's streaming APIs, you can iterate over Scala collections throug `scala.collection.JavaConversions`. This is the thing that helped my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public KafkaProducer(String zookeeperAddress, String topic) throws IOException,
        KeeperException, InterruptedException {

    this.zookeeperAddress = zookeeperAddress;
    this.topic = topic;

    ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper(zookeeperAddress, 10000, null);
    List<String> brokerList = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> ids = zk.getChildren("/brokers/ids", false);
    for (String id : ids) {
        String brokerInfoString = new String(zk.getData("/brokers/ids/" + id, false, null));
        Broker broker = Broker.createBroker(Integer.valueOf(id), brokerInfoString);
        if (broker != null) {
            brokerList.add(broker.connectionString());
        }
    }

    props.put("serializer.class", KAFKA_STRING_ENCODER);
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", String.join(",", brokerList));
    producer = new Producer<String, String>(new ProducerConfig(props));
}
```