# Java Compiler Cannot Find Kafka Class

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I'm having problem using the last answer of this question in my Java code.
[Kafka: Get broker host from ZooKeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490113/kafka-get-broker-host-from-zookeeper)

Specifically, it fails finding the last argument on this line:

```
ZkClient client = new ZkClient("localhost:2181", 10000, kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer);
```

I'm using Maven and these are the dependencies in the pom.xml if it matters.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
                <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
                <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you get a compile time issue?

Comment: @localhost999 Yes, it's compile time issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
ZkClient client = new ZkClient("localhost:2181", Integer.MAX_VALUE,10000, kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
```

kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer is a scala object. To use scala object in java you have to use like above.

Comment: Thanks!  It works!  I would have never figured that out since I'm still a newbie in Scala.