# kafka get partition count for a topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How can I get number of partitions for any kafka topic from the code. I have researched many links but none seem to work.

Mentioning a few:

http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/148132gdzk/find-topic-partition-count-through-simpleclient-api

http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/151cv3htga/get-replication-and-partition-count-of-a-topic

http://qnalist.com/questions/5809219/get-replication-and-partition-count-of-a-topic

which look like similar discussions.

Also there are similar links on SO which do not have a working solution to this.

Comment: Which Kafka version?

Comment: vish4071, how about accepting the solution you ended up using?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the 0.82 Producer API and 0.9 Consumer api you can use something like

```
Properties configProperties = new Properties();
configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);
producer.partitionsFor("test")
```

Comment: This assumes that I'm using KafkaConsumer for my consumer, but I'm using ConsumerConnector for it. refer: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

Comment: My app is sharded, because I'm using KafkaStreams. So this code actually outputs only the partitions assigned to the particular pod where the KafkaProducer is created which is only a fraction of total partitions of the topic.

Answer (score 133):

Go to your `kafka/bin` directory.

Then run this:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic_name
```

You should see what you need under `PartitionCount`.

```
Topic:topic_name        PartitionCount:5        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: topic_name       Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: topic_name       Partition: 1    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: topic_name       Partition: 2    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: topic_name       Partition: 3    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: topic_name       Partition: 4    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

---

When using a version where zookeeper is no longer a dependency of Kafka

```
kafka-topics --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic_name
```

Comment: Upvoting because I happened to be searching for a non-code solution and this was perfect.

Comment: If you want to sum up all partitions (including replicas) for a topic regex see my answer below.

Comment: there is no "PartitionCount" field for me. each partition has its own line but not a total partition count field to be seen.

Answer (score 12):

In java code we can use `AdminClient` to get sum partions of one topic.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "host:9092");
AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(props);

DescribeTopicsResult result = client.describeTopics(Arrays.asList("TEST"));
Map<String, KafkaFuture<TopicDescription>>  values = result.values();
KafkaFuture<TopicDescription> topicDescription = values.get("TEST");
int partitions = topicDescription.get().partitions().size();
System.out.println(partitions);
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I do it:

```
  /**
   * Retrieves list of all partitions IDs of the given {@code topic}.
   * 
   * @param topic
   * @param seedBrokers List of known brokers of a Kafka cluster
   * @return list of partitions or empty list if none found
   */
  public static List<Integer> getPartitionsForTopic(String topic, List<BrokerInfo> seedBrokers) {
    for (BrokerInfo seed : seedBrokers) {
      SimpleConsumer consumer = null;
      try {
        consumer = new SimpleConsumer(seed.getHost(), seed.getPort(), 20000, 128 * 1024, "partitionLookup");
        List<String> topics = Collections.singletonList(topic);
        TopicMetadataRequest req = new TopicMetadataRequest(topics);
        kafka.javaapi.TopicMetadataResponse resp = consumer.send(req);

        List<Integer> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        // find our partition's metadata
        List<TopicMetadata> metaData = resp.topicsMetadata();
        for (TopicMetadata item : metaData) {
          for (PartitionMetadata part : item.partitionsMetadata()) {
            partitions.add(part.partitionId());
          }
        }
        return partitions;  // leave on first successful broker (every broker has this info)
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // try all available brokers, so just report error and go to next one
        LOG.error("Error communicating with broker [" + seed + "] to find list of partitions for [" + topic + "]. Reason: " + e);
      } finally {
        if (consumer != null)
          consumer.close();
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeError("Could not get partitions");
  }
```

Note that I just needed to pull out partition IDs, but you can additionally retrieve any other partition metadata, like `leader`, `isr`, `replicas`, ...
And `BrokerInfo` is just a simple POJO that has `host` and `port` fields.

Answer (score 8):

Below shell cmd can print the number of partitions. You should be in kafka bin directory before executing the cmd:

```
sh kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic **TopicName** | awk '{print $2}' | uniq -c |awk 'NR==2{print "count of partitions=" $1}'
```

Note that you have to change the topic name according to your need. 
You can further validate this using if condition as well:

```
sh kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic **TopicName** | awk '{print $2}' | uniq -c |awk 'NR==2{if ($1=="16") print "valid partitions"}'
```

The above cmd command prints valid partitions if count is 16. You can change count depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

**Use PartitionList from KafkaConsumer**

```
     //create consumer then loop through topics
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    List<PartitionInfo> partitions = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);

    ArrayList<Integer> partitionList = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(partitions.get(0).partition());

    for(int i = 0; i < partitions.size(); i++){
        partitionList.add(partitions.get(i).partition());
    }

    Collections.sort(partitionList);
```

Should work like a charm. Let me know if there's a simpler way to access Partition List from Topic.

Answer (score 4):

So the following approach works for kafka 0.10 and it does not use any producer or consumer APIs. It uses some classes from the scala API in kafka such as ZkConnection and ZkUtils.

```
    ZkConnection zkConnection = new ZkConnection(zkConnect);
    ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient,zkConnection,false);
    System.out.println(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(zkUtils.getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(
         JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(topicList))).get("bidlogs_kafka10").size());
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue, where I needed to get the partitions for a topic.

With the help of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521307/1314742) I was able to get the information from Zookeeper.

Here is my code in Scala (but could be easily translated into Java)

```
import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper

def extractPartitionNumberForTopic(topicName: String, zookeeperQurom: String): Int = {
  val zk = new ZooKeeper(zookeeperQurom, 10000, null);
  val zkNodeName = s"/brokers/topics/$topicName/partitions"
  val numPartitions = zk.getChildren(zkNodeName, false).size
  zk.close()
  numPartitions
}
```

Using this approach allowed me to access the information about Kafka topics as well as other information about Kafka brokers ...

**From Zookeeper** you could check for the number of partitions for a topic by browsing to `/brokers/topics/MY_TOPIC_NAME/partitions`

Using `zookeeper-client.sh` to connect to your zookeeper:

```
[zk: ZkServer:2181(CONNECTED) 5] ls /brokers/topics/MY_TOPIC_NAME/partitions
[0, 1, 2]
```

That shows us that there are 3 partitions for the topic `MY_TOPIC_NAME`

Answer (score 3):

```
//create the kafka producer
def getKafkaProducer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = {
val kafkaProps: Properties = new Properties()
kafkaProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
kafkaProps.put("key.serializer",
"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
kafkaProps.put("value.serializer", 
"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaProps)
}
val kafkaProducer = getKafkaProducer
val noOfPartition = kafkaProducer.partitionsFor("TopicName") 
println(noOfPartition) //it will print the number of partiton for the given 
//topic
```

Comment: In newer versions(kafka-python), it's `KafkaConsumer.partitions_for_topic('TopicName')` returns a set of all partitions ids.

Answer (score 2):

@Sunil-patil answer stopped short of answering the count piece of it. You have to get the size of the List

producer.partitionsFor("test").size()

@vish4071 no point butting Sunil, you did not mention that you are using ConsumerConnector in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The number of partitions can be retrieved from zookeeper-shell

```
Syntax: ls /brokers/topics/<topic_name>/partitions
```

Below is the example:

```
root@zookeeper-01:/opt/kafka_2.11-2.0.0# bin/zookeeper-shell.sh zookeeper-01:2181
Connecting to zookeeper-01:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
ls /brokers/topics/test/partitions
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get kafka partition list from zookeeper like this.
It is real kafka server side partition number.

```
[zk: zk.kafka:2181(CONNECTED) 43] ls /users/test_account/test_kafka_name/brokers/topics/test_kafka_topic_name/partitions
[35, 36, 159, 33, 34, 158, 157, 39, 156, 37, 155, 38, 154, 152, 153, 150, 151, 43, 42, 41, 40, 202, 203, 204, 205, 200, 201, 22, 23, 169, 24, 25, 26, 166, 206, 165, 27, 207, 168, 208, 28, 29, 167, 209, 161, 3, 2, 162, 1, 163, 0, 164, 7, 30, 6, 32, 5, 160, 31, 4, 9, 8, 211, 212, 210, 215, 216, 213, 19, 214, 17, 179, 219, 18, 178, 177, 15, 217, 218, 16, 176, 13, 14, 11, 12, 21, 170, 20, 171, 174, 175, 172, 173, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 188, 228, 187, 229, 189, 180, 10, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 116, 117, 79, 114, 78, 77, 115, 112, 113, 110, 111, 118, 119, 82, 83, 80, 81, 86, 87, 84, 85, 67, 125, 66, 126, 69, 127, 128, 68, 121, 122, 123, 124, 129, 70, 71, 120, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 134, 135, 132, 133, 59, 138, 58, 57, 139, 136, 56, 137, 55, 64, 65, 62, 63, 60, 131, 130, 61, 49, 143, 48, 144, 145, 146, 45, 147, 44, 148, 47, 149, 46, 51, 52, 53, 54, 140, 142, 141, 50, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 99, 102, 101, 100, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 88, 89, 195, 194, 197, 196, 191, 190, 193, 192, 198, 199, 230, 239, 232, 231, 234, 233, 236, 235, 238, 237]
```

And you can use partition count at consumer code.

```scala
  def getNumPartitions(topic: String): Int = {
    val zk = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkHostList, new RetryNTimes(5, 1000))

    zk.start()
    var numPartitions: Int = 0
    val topicPartitionsPath = zkPath + "/brokers/topics/" + topic + "/partitions"

    if (zk.checkExists().forPath(topicPartitionsPath) != null) {
        try {
            val brokerIdList = zk.getChildren().forPath(topicPartitionsPath).asScala
            numPartitions = brokerIdList.length.toInt
        } catch {
            case e: Exception => {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }  
        }  
    }  
    zk.close()

    numPartitions
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of partitions the ideal/actual way is to use the AdminClients API

```
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    AdminClient adminClient=KafkaAdminClient.create(properties);
    Map<String, TopicDescription> jension = adminClient.describeTopics(Collections.singletonList("jenison")).all().get();
    System.out.println(jension.get("jenison").partitions().size());
```

This can be run as a standalone java method with no producer/consumer dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the `kafka.utils.ZkUtils` which has many methods aimed to help extract metadata about the cluster. The answers here are nice so I'm just adding for the sake of diversity:

```
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient

def getTopicPartitionCount(zookeeperQuorum: String, topic: String): Int = {
  val client = new ZkClient(zookeeperQuorum)
  val partitionCount = ZkUtils.getAllPartitions(client)
    .count(topicPartitionPair => topicPartitionPair.topic == topic)

  client.close
  partitionCount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topicName).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found none of the answers provided a quick easy way to count all the partitions for a given topic regex. In my case I needed to see how many partitions there were in my cluster including replicas for sizing purposes.

Below is the bash command you can run (no extra tools needed):

```sh
kafka-topics --describe --bootstrap-server broker --topic ".*" | grep Configs | awk '{printf "%d\n", $4*$6}' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

You can adjust the topic regex by replacing the `.*` regex with whatever you like. Also make sure to change `broker` to your broker's address.

Details:

1. Stream `kafka-topics` describe output for the given topics of interest
2. Extract only the first line for each topic which contains the partition count and replication factor
3. Multiply PartitionCount by ReplicationFactor to get total partitions for the topic
4. Sum all counts and print total

Bonus:

If you have docker installed you don't need to download the Kafka binary:

```sh
docker run -it confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0 /bin/bash
```

Then you can run this to access all the Kafka scripts:

```sh
cd /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for python confluent-kafka packages

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient

topic_name = 'my_topic'
settings  = {'bootstrap.servers': ["..."]}
kadmin = AdminClient(settings)
topic_metadata = kadmin.list_topics(topic_name).topics
```