# Getting the number of partitions in the producer in kafka 0.8.0 using partitionsFor method

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, producer

Do we have a support for `partitionsFor` method in the producer in kafka version 0.8.0? I want to use this method to get the number of partitions given a kafka topic.

If this method is not available in kafka 0.8.0, what is the easiest way to get the number of partitions in the producer in this specific version of kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use listTopics() method also

```
    ArrayList<Topics> topicList = new ArrayList<Topics>();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Map<String, List<PartitionInfo>> topics;
    Topics topic;
    InputStream input = 
 getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("kafkaCluster.properties");
    try {
        props.load(input);
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
 props.getProperty("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG"));
        props.put("key.deserializer", 
 "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", 
 "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, 
   String>(props);
        topics = consumer.listTopics();
        // System.out.println(topics.get(topics));
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<PartitionInfo>> entry : 
    topics.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + 
     entry.getValue());
            topic = new Topics();
            topic.setTopic_name(entry.getKey());
            topic.setPartitions(Integer.toString(entry.getValue().size()));
            topicList.add(topic);
        }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Here the number of elements in array is the number of partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try following approach
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458605/5922904.
Also ZkUtils have the method getPartitionsForTopics which can also be used. Although I have not tried and tested it myself