# Kafka JMX to get partition for a topic in one broker

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I know we could use **script** to get partition count for a topic ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437681/kafka-get-partition-count-for-a-topic)), like following,

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic_name
```

The result is

```
Topic:topic_name    PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
      Topic: topic_name Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
      Topic: topic_name Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

How could we use **JMX** to monitor the number of partitions for a specific topic in one broker?

Comment: Have you taken a look through the existing Mbeans in the JMX console?

Comment: @cricket_007 I've checked [JMX Mbeans List](https://gist.github.com/thbkrkr/77c8f6f9a301d7b16555726793af8301), not find anything I wanted. And it seems that this JMX Mbean List is not official. I cannot find any official JMX Mbeans document

Comment: The JMX patterns are on the Confluent site https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#server-metrics as well as Kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring