# How can I get a list of all `PartitionTopic`s for a topic in Confluent.Kafka?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I am using [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) (Confluent.Kafka) to produce messages for Kafka.

I would like to manually manage which partitions messages go to in order to preserve order for certain groups of messages.

How is it possible to get a list of `PartitionTopic` for a Kafka topic?

I have looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437681/kafka-get-partition-count-for-a-topic) in Java.
But I don't understand how to achieve the same functionality with `Confluent.Kafka`.

Alternatively, it would be acceptable to send messages with keys, because the same keys are guaranteed to be on the same partitions. But again, I could not find a way to create a `new Message` with any key type other than `Null`. So, an example of sending a message with a non-null key would be helpful.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] which includes where you are attempting to set the partition key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of TopicPartitions for a single topic you could use AdminClient class:

```
using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = "bootstrap-servers" }).Build())
{
    var meta = adminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

    var topic = meta.Topics.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Topic == "topic-name");

    var topicPartitions = topic.Partitions;
}
```

You can find more AdminClient examples [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdminClient/Program.cs). But notice the warnings, saying that: "The API for this functionality is subject to change."

Comment: This doesn't work. This returns TopicMetadata which has PartitionMetadata. In the KafkaAdmin, the PartitionTopic is a different object.

Comment: @TheAlgorist There is no such class `PartitionTopic` in confluent-kafka-dotnet. Maybe you are referring to the `TopicPartition`? If you are, then the `PartitionMetadata` retrieved from `AdminClient` and the topic name is sufficient to construct the `TopicPartition` objects for your topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out that the reason I could not create messages with a non-null key was because I had specified my Producer with `<Null, ...>`.

Thank you to [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) for asking me for minimal reproducible example, which prompted me to work this out.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to explicitly configure the offsets of a specific consumer for a topic, you have to set the offset PER TopicPartition.  This requires having updated Metadata for the cluster.  For example:

```
        Metadata meta = adminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        // Query where the offset is for each partition.
        foreach (TopicMetadata topicMeta in kafkaMetadata.Topics)
        {
            if (topicMeta.Topic == "sometopic")
            {
                for (int i=0; i<topicMeta.Partitions.Count; i++)
                {
                    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topic, topicMeta.Partitions[i].PartitionId);
                    WatermarkOffsets wo = consumer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(tp, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                    //consumer.Seek(new TopicPartitionOffset(tp, wo.High));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't mind the down-voting for this not answering the question head-on, but what I was attempting to show was exactly how you construct a new TopicPartition based on the AdminClient.  There isn't another example of it here, and it's not obvious that it's legal to just make a new one when needed.