# The api to find died brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Is there any API to find dead `brokers` and running `brokers` of `kafka`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490113/kafka-get-broker-host-from-zookeeper

Comment: Dead brokers usually mean they are already unregistered from within the zookeeper, so you could find them nowhere.