# scala- how can I confirm specific topic exists in Kafka server(broker)?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using scala, spark, and Kafka.   I have 2 questions.

1.how can I confirm the topic exists in Kafka broker(server)?

2.how can I confirm the Kafka server (bootstrap server) is running or not?

```
object kafkaProducer extends App {

  def sendMessages(): Unit = {


//define topic
val topic = "spark-topic"       // how can i confirm this topic is exist in kafka server ? 

//define producer properties
val props = new java.util.Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
props.put("client.id", "KafkaProducer")
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer")

//create producer instance
val kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, JsonNode](props)

//create object mapper
val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

//mapper Json object to string
      def toJson(value: Any): String = {
        mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
      }


//send producer message

    val jsonstring =
      s"""{
         | "id": "0001",
         | "name": "Peter"
         |}
      """.stripMargin

    val jsonNode: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonstring)
    val rec = new ProducerRecord[String, JsonNode](topic, jsonNode)
    kafkaProducer.send(rec)
    //println(rec)

  }

}
```

Comment: Use this util class to know if topic exists https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ListTopicCommand.scala
To know health of the brokers https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521307/3595618

Answer (score 0):

1) The recommended way to check if a topic exists is to use the AdminClient API.

You can use [`listTopics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listTopics--) or [`describeTopics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeTopics-java.util.Collection-).

2) Assuming you don't have any privilege access to the cluster (to check metrics or liveness probes), the only way to check the cluster is running is to try connecting to/use it.

With the AdminClient, you can use [`describeCluster()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html#describeCluster-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeClusterOptions-), for example, to attempt to retrieve the state of the cluster.

Comment: Is there any particular method is available to check whether a particular topic exists or not .. Like this ---> spark.catalog.tableExists(tablename)

Comment: Unfortunately not with the public APIs, you have to use either `listTopics()` or `describeTopics()` and interpret their result and that's pretty easy.